# apt-get failed to fetch package

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, apt

I want to install curl on my ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

It gave the following error:

```
Err http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main curl i386 7.21.0-1ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 193.206.140.45 80]
Failed to fetch http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/curl_7.21.0-1ubuntu1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 193.206.140.45 80]
```

Then I did an update and retried install. But this didn't make any difference.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

What should I do?

Comment: Can you show the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Maverick Meerkat? It's no longer supported, which is presumably why you're not able to install curl.

You will need to upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu or manually install one.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I'm sorry to tell you that if you're running Ubuntu Maverick Meerkat it is no longer supported. ***Read:*** [Maverick Meerkat No Longer Supported](http://www.pcworld.com/article/253594/say_goodbye_to_ubuntu_linux_10_10_maverick_meerkat.html) Please Upgrade or Manually install a newer version of Ubuntu. The latest stable version is Ubuntu 13.04.